# Accessing I2C bus using multithread i python, mutex

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, i2c

Greeting,
I have launched a multi thread program consisting of three thread executing concurrently; However, inside these functions there is data acquisition  from a 4 pressure sensors through I2C communication, but I cannot access more one sensor at a time hence the multithreading process gives strange data while reading different sensor data at a time I have thought about using mutex in order to permit single access for the bus.
I shared a part of the code for starting the threads and waiting for the thread to terminate, but  I  do not how can I establish mutex,
the three threads need to run concurrently, but how can they access the i2c bus one by one. Any help ?

```
thread1=threading.Thread(target=Controlling,args=(dp1,1,1))    
thread2=threading.Thread(target=Controlling,args=(dp2,2,3))
thread3=threading.Thread(target=Controlling,args=(dp3,3,4))

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
thread3.join()

def Controlling(dp,num,bus):
    motor   = MotorKit()
    valve   = MotorKit(address=0x28)     
    rpi = pigpio.pi()
    numericalPressure = getPressure(bus, rpi)
    print(nemericalPressure)

def getPressure(bus, pRaspberryPi):
    sensorAdr = 0x69
    outMax = 25500
    outMin = 1000   
    pMax   = 2000
    pMin   = 0
       
    readBytes = 2
    handle      = pRaspberryPi.i2c_open(bus, sensorAdr)
    count, data = pRaspberryPi.i2c_read_device(handle, readBytes)
    pRaspberryPi.i2c_close(handle)
    digitalPressure = data[0] << 8 | data[1]     
    return digitalPressure
```

This is a summary of the program, and as you can see all three functions are trying to access the buses the same time, but this give me a random value of the acquired pressure.
Please do not focus on the taping error while writing the program
Any solution using mutex will be appreciated

Comment: I would not allow three different threads to access the bus. I would have one thread continually read the sensors, and publish the values in shared variables that other threads could examine without any need to wait.

Comment: A mutex would resolve this, and they're easy to use.  Have you tried it?

Comment: I did not use mutex before, but I will try to do you have a sample code that maybe helpful